# Does a closed question count towards the accept rate ?

Tags: support, closed-questions

The following question was closed without any answer :

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7755/i-have-to-send-my-new-archos-101-pad-for-repair-screen-wont-display-anyone-an

Does this influence  my accept rate ?

Can I still reach a 100% accept rate now ?

Comment: @Al Everett : I 'm just one of those guys that like to tidy up , that's all. And apart from that: sometimes I just wonder about such things. It has helped me a lot over the years just to get to know and understand systems I am using ( any system I am using). Not necessarily because I need it now, but simple because I want to know it ( and think I am going to be able to use that knowledge in the future ).

Comment: [Accept rate is no longer displayed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate/164654#164654).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [the blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/):

- The accept rate is the percentage of answers accepted based on the questions asked by the user.
- The accept rate is calculated on questions that are older than 3 days.
- The accept rate is heavily cached and can take 24hrs or more to update.
- The accept rate is only calculated when the user has 4 or more questions.

#### Which questions do not affect the accept rate?

The following questions are not included in the accept rate calculation:

- Community Wiki Questions
- Closed Questions
- Questions with no answers

#### What does the accept rate mean?

- If the stat doesn’t appear at all, it’s a new user, or someone who rarely asks questions.
- If you see a low percentage, it’s a user who asks a lot of questions but accepts almost no answers.
- If you see a high percentage, it’s an engaged user, someone who frequently goes back and interacts with their questions after asking.
- If you see a middle of the road percentage, it’s an experienced user who understands what accepted answers are for.